# How to check the on change event in multiple elements with same class name in Rails using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

in a rails module, when user enters less than 0 value he should get invalid message.

in js file i have written a onchange function which expecting when a textbox gets less than zero value this function should trigger an alert.

```
$(document).on('onchange',".default-value" (function(event) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.default-value').each(function(){
     var num = $(this).val();
     if( num < 0)  
      alert("Invalid Entry");
  });
});
```

in my slim.erb file i have written following code.in here the text box values are to be held and sent for the function i have written inside the js file.

```
 = y.input :default_value, label: false, input_html: { class: "default-value #{ y.object.parameter.parameterize } " }
```

I expect an invalid error right when I type less than 0 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update with

```
    $(".default-value").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() < 0) {
         $(this).val('');
         alert("Invalid Entry");

       }
   });
```

Comment: sir i put your code inside $document.change function so  i am getting the alert now  but if i change one textbox its giving me a series of alerts.

Comment: Now it is not working. sir i have to get  "default-value #{ y.object.parameter.parameterize } "  value in my js file. how  can i change my syntax sir

Comment: sorry for the late reply sir...  i can give you an example of classname of one text box. " string optional form-control default-value  dls-g50-score  " ,like this i have many text boxes.  as it is displaying in a loop we have same classname for every text box and to differentiate it we are parameterising its lable name with class name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193883/discussion-between-bhupati-and-gangothri).

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger on change event as below:

```
$('.value_check').on('change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() < 0 ){
    $(this).val('');
    alert("Invalid Entry");
  }
});
```

Since you have multiple element with same class, here you can assign new class to this like:

```
= y.input :default_value, label: false, input_html: { class: "default-value value_check #{ y.object.parameter.parameterize } " }
```

Comment: i need each function as there is multiple textboxes with same class name. but still i worked your suggestion it didnt work.

Comment: if you have multiple element with that class then you can assign seperate class for it. i will update above